# Querying multiple tables in athena aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want to extract the oldest timestamp from a column in a table. I want to do this for all the tables in athena aws. Can I write a script or is there any way to automate it instead of running the query again and again for all the tables?

Answer (score 0):

**"is there any way to automate it"**

IF you want to automate querying data by using Athena, one solution is to write a Lambda function in the programming language of your choice. In the Lambda function, use a given Athena API to perform the actual query operation. Then you can set schedule events so the Lambda function is invoked on a regular schedule.